# Javascript Array works fine, but starts over if you leave the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

Working at learning Javascript. I have this code, and it works fine. My question is, when I create the array from a form, leave the page and come back to the page, add new numbers to the array, but the array starts over with the new numbers.  **Is there a way to keep the original array and push new numbers to it?** Or is that just the way Javascript works?

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const show = document.getElementById('show');
let numArray = [];
//!number equals whatever is sent to this function
function getPushed(number) {
  numArray.push(number);
  localStorage.setItem('knife', JSON.stringify(numArray));
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const numberToAdd = document.getElementById('numberAdd').value;
  parseInt(numberToAdd);
  show.innerHTML = numberToAdd;
  getPushed(numberToAdd);
});
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: You never read from `localStorage`....

Comment: How does that change the fact the array starts over with new numbers?

Comment: What new numbers? Also, `parseInt(numberToAdd);` does not change `numberToAdd`. Use `const numberToAdd = parseInt(document.getElementById('numberAdd').value)` instead.

Comment: @D.Pardal Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are creating a new array on every page load instead of using the array that you saved in the local storage. That's why the array *starts over* each time.

Instead check if there is already data stored in the `'knife'` key. If there is then use it, otherwise default back to the newly created array.

```
let numArray = [];
let storedData = localStorage.getItem('knife');
if (storedData !== null) {
  numArray = JSON.parse(storedData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that should have been obvious to me. I appreciate your help